# Which parameter in the Omniauth hash do you use to persist the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, omniauth

Ok, totally confused with Omniauth, this is what I have so far:

- Got omniauth with the linkein strategy working all good.
- I click on a button, I get redirected to linked in, my callback is called, I receive the ominauth hash with all the info for that user from linkedin.

Now, when I go to created/or fetch my user in my database that is, or is going to be linked to this linkedin account, which value from the Omniauth hash do I treat as the consistent "user id" for this user? So that I can identify the user on future returns?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the `uid` field. That is the only way to identify a user.

In some specific cases (like when using OmniAuth with Google) you can actually link the omniauth user to an already existing account by using his email. But be careful when doing this linking, you don't want to link 2 different users together. Always make sure that there is a `verified_email` field inside the omniauth hash.